# CALayer remove transparent masking

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I am working on an ios application and i have a issue using CALayer it has created a transparent mask on every image i put in the Layer.
Please have a look at the code below :

```
self.mask = [CALayer layer];
self.mask.contents = CFBridgingRelease(([UIImage imageNamed:@"launch screen.png"].CGImage));
self.mask.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200);
self.mask.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
self.mask.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetMidY(self.view.bounds));

self.imageView = _imageView;
self.view.layer.mask = self.mask;
```

Please Refer to this image for example : 
http://31.media.tumblr.com/10cc0ba92377a2cba9fb35c9943fd2ca/tumblr_inline_n6zpokNxpC1qh9cw7.gif

Comment: Can you clarify an issue that you have an outcome that you need? It is not clear now from your definition what problem you have.

Comment: See the twitter logo in the center of the SplashScreen it is transparent from the code not from the image it's self i don't want it transparent.

Comment: You should add your image as a subview then, not as a mask. Mask purpose is to "cut" views as you show.

Comment: Can you help me showing it how to do it ?

Comment: It would be not a five minute challenge, I think you will need to work on this code on your own. If you wrote the code above, you will be able to write a simple addSubview as well.